# In Haskell, how to copy immutable array into a mutable array from a specific index

Tags: arrays, haskell, functional-programming, copy

I have two arrays of the following types:

```
a :: IOArray Word16 Word16
b :: [Word16]
```

and I want a function **copyAtPositionI** that copies all the elements of array **b** into array **a** beginning at the ith index of array **a**. It can be assumed that the index will not be such that it attempts to copy elements out of the bounds of the array **a**.

The function should be of the following type:

```
copyAtPositionI :: IOArray Word16 Word16 -> [Word16] -> Word16 -> IO ()
```

For example (this is not Haskell),

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [10, 11, 12, 13]
```

**copyAtPositionI a b 3** should result in **a** being equal to **[1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 8, 9]**

I did not find any functions in the Data.Array.IO package that does exactly what I want. I only found the function [writeArray](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Array-MArray.html#v:writeArray) in the **Data.Array.MArray** package but I do not know how to execute the function for every element in the array **b**.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to [`mapM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_) an insertion action over your list `b`.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to apply it, using an index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `zipWithM_`:

```
copyAtPositionI mut imm i = zipWithM_ (writeArray mut) [i..] imm
```

If you didn't have it, you could implement it in a pretty straightforward way:

```
zipWithM_ f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y >> zipWithM_ f xs ys
zipWithM_ f _ _ = return ()
```

Comment: You are my hero.